# Saving a screenshot in CoCos2d V2.xx using CCRenderTexture

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, screenshot

I know there are quite a few examples of how to save a screen in CoCos2d using CCRenderTexture, but they just don't seem to work for me. I've written a coloring book application for a client and they, of course, want to be able to save out images. I've tried a ton of different ways and bastardized a bunch of examples to no avail. Lately, I've been receiving this error:

> 2012-03-24 13:07:03.749 Coloring Book[823:1be03] cocos2d: ERROR:
>   Failed to save file:/Users/macbookpro/Library/Application
>   Support/iPhone
>   Simulator/5.1/Applications/76F88977-AD3A-47B8-8026-C9324BB3636E/Documents/Users/macbookpro/Library/Application Support/iPhone
>   Simulator/5.1/Applications/76F88977-AD3A-47B8-8026-C9324BB3636E/Documents/testimagename.png
>   to disk

I get something similar when running from the device. Here's my screenshot code:

```
- (void) takeScreenShot
  {
     NSString* file = @"testimagename.png";

NSArray* paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString* documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* screenshotPath = [documentsDirectory 
                            stringByAppendingPathComponent:file];

[CCDirector sharedDirector].nextDeltaTimeZero = YES;

CGSize winSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;
CCRenderTexture* rtx = 
[CCRenderTexture renderTextureWithWidth:winSize.width 
                                 height:winSize.height];
[rtx begin];
[Page visit];
[rtx end];

// save as file as PNG
[rtx  saveToFile:screenshotPath
         format:kCCImageFormatPNG];
 }
```

It's probably something simple, but it has been driving me nuts for a few days! Please, Stack Overflow, make me feel stupid and fix my problem!

Comment: step into the saveToFile method. If it returns an NSError object see if that gives you more info (ie permission denied, not enough disk space, etc). If that doesn't help try saving any file to the same path, for example using NSString writeToFile and providing an NSError object that may give you more info.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D - First, thanks for the reply! OK, I stepped through and it's not giving any errors. It gets through the `if( format == kCCImageFormatPNG )
  imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation( image );` segment of the saveToFile section. It just returns FALSE for the success variable, so it has to be failing during commit. I'm going to try saving something else real quick.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D OK, I just saved a file into the Documents folder just fine with writeToFile, so shouldn't be path.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem I was having comes down to defining a path. You don't need to define a path to the Documents section of the device, Cocos2D saves it to the Documents by default. I put this together (note thanks very much to LearnCocos2D for some of the code I'm using) to save the layers I want and then save the screen to the Photo Library.

```
- (void) takeScreenShot
{

//name the file we want to save in documents
NSString* file = @"//imageforphotolib.png";

//get the path to the Documents directory
NSArray* paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString* documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* screenshotPath = [documentsDirectory 
                            stringByAppendingPathComponent:file];

[CCDirector sharedDirector].nextDeltaTimeZero = YES;

//creating standard screensize variable
CGSize winSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;

//we're using transparancies as the images, 
//so we load this white page to give a backdrop
CCSprite *whitePage = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"whitePage.png"];
whitePage.position = ccp(winSize.width/2, winSize.height/2);

//create a render texture to hold our images
CCRenderTexture* rtx = 
[CCRenderTexture renderTextureWithWidth:winSize.width 
                                 height:winSize.height];
[rtx begin];// open the texture
[whitePage visit];//add a white page to the background
[Page visit];//put in the background image
[target visit];//put in the coloring layer
[rtx end];//close the texture

// save as file as PNG
[rtx  saveToFile:@"imageforphotolib.png"
         format:kCCImageFormatPNG];

//get the screenshot as raw data
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:screenshotPath];
//create an image from the raw data
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
//save the image to the users Photo Library
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(img, nil, nil, nil);
 }
```